# Can I encrypt Node.js TCP traffic with TLS so it's impossible to read?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, https, tls1.2

So I currently have a node.js app that reads my website user ips from a file and using geoip places a dot in a map for each visitor location.

Problem is, everytime a new visitor comes the message sent through the websocket can be seen by the client if he inspects traffic with wireshark or fiddler.

Obviously displaying user ips is out of the question, so I am wondering if using TLS would be enough to make this information unreadable or impossible to debug from the javascript code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information is sent *to the user's browser*. The browser ***must*** be able to decode it to be able to work with it. The browser also incidentally offers debugging tools which allow the user to inspect everything that's going on. Ergo, the user is able to inspect anything and everything that the browser can. **No, what you want is not possible.** If the information is confidential, never send it to any client in the first place.

Comment: Well, my messages are tailed directly from a file to the server, and the server gets this ip in order for the client to get the location in map (since map js file generates all this data on the client side)

I guess the way the script handles all this makes it necessary to have the ip being sent to the client side, so then geoip can convert it to the right location on the map.

So then, TLS is not an option here ? 

I assume that would need to remake all the logic so that the dots in map are based on a previously defined location sent to client instead of an ip being converted by geoip then.

Comment: It's pretty simple: data that resides on your server is private, any data that your server discloses and sends out over the wire must be considered public. You probably have to move that work to the server so the server only sends out data relevant to make a map, without disclosing the underlying IPs.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about that, what is TLS all about then ?

I've just done some tests visiting a TLS Node App and I can't ready any message from the websockets in plain text, neither do I belive TLS can be easily decrypted (although its predecessor can)

Comment: It's a ***Transport*** Layer encryption, it protects against 3rd parties reading the communication between you and a server. Obviously both you and the server must be able to decrypt the data, otherwise there's no point in sending any data in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

It will make it more-or-less impossible to sniff the data in transit.

It does nothing to stop people taking your JS and tweaking it slightly to log the data after the browser has received it.

You can't hide data you send to the browser from the person who controls the browser.

Comment: @Rdang — and then it gets decrypted as it comes out of the network connection and into the browser since your JavaScript, running in the browser, has to be able to read it (and it can't do that if it is still encrypted).

Comment: Yea you're right ofcourse. TLS seems to make the websocket TCP data impossible to read from wireshark but as you said, it could be debuged by JS.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest question is why are you sending the IP and the position to the browser? To place the marker on the map, you just need the position.

If you need to distinct the users by IP address on the client side, you could write an own hashing algorithm which concats the ip with a predefined string(secret). So the identifier is always the same for the same IP, but the IP is not reconstructable without the corresponding secret.

Comment: That seems like a good suggestion Torben .
You are suggesting to add a secret to the server ?
How exactly would that work though considering the ip needs to be sent to the app (client side) to determine the location, since it relies on geoip for this purpose?

Comment: @Rdang What's the problem in having the *server* do the GeoIP lookup and just send the location, without IP, to the client?!

Comment: @deceze, well although I have considered that possibility it will imply totally changing the app logic, since currently it uses a geo.ip variable to define the location by using node geoip module and a lot of other parts of the code use it as well.

I am trying to figure which is my best option here, totally remaking the server and app to do it the way you are saying or implementing encryption while maintaining server / app current logic

Comment: @Rdang Well, your app logic is failing at a basic level here, so you'll have to redo it. If you send IP data to the client, then the client will (have to) read it. Period. End of story. No way around that.

Comment: I understand, TSL provides encryption up to an extend and the TCP websocket data seems to be unreadable from wireshark or browser, but I guess js will still allow to decrypt it.

Will probably just have to remake most of it then, thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0):

TLS helps against traffic snipping by 3rd party attackers. If normal users can access sensitive information, then TLS worths nothing. It is called *Transport Layer* Security for a good reason.